# Does Redis Cache support query ability

Tags: java, redis

I am learning redis cache, just wanted to know it supports query ability.

We have location table , want to store the records in redis cache(Need to search by location name or id).

Let me know how we build a key for the same.

or Do we need to add two entry into redis cache

```
 jedis.set(TenantId+LocationName, Location)

 jedis.set(TenantId+LocationId, Location)
```

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis allows querying, but like other NoSQL databases, you want to have the data stored in it according to how you're going to query it. If you need to query by either name or id, you'll need two "entries" to facilitate that (BTW, this isn't so different than what an RDBMS does with indices).

Instead, however, of creating two keys - one for name lookups and the other for id - with the [`SET`](http://redis.io/commands/set) command, you should consider using the Hash data structure. For each tenant keep a Hash with two fields per location - one that maps from name to id and vice versa. In very pseudo-Java calling [`HMSET`](http://redis.io/commands/hmset) would look like:

```
jedis.hmset(TenantId, <LocationName, Location, locationId, Location>);
```